# task must be cleared before being run

Tags: airflow

I have a task that's scheduled to run hourly, however it's not being triggered. When I look at the`Task Instance Details` it says:

```
All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon unless:
- The scheduler is down or under heavy load
- The following configuration values may be limiting the number of queueable processes: parallelism, dag_concurrency, max_active_dag_runs_per_dag, non_pooled_task_slot_count
- This task instance already ran and had its state changed manually (e.g. cleared in the UI)

If this task instance does not start soon please contact your Airflow administrator for assistance.
```

If I clear the task in the UI I am able to execute it through terminal but it does not run when scheduled.

Why do I have to manually clear it after every run?